# py2.7 label text function fails

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

Button not putting text in label with btnWork function. This is as simple as I can make the code. I'm hoping, this will finally explain this problem for me.
Please help me.
Thanks So Much

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("200x200")
root.title('label')
root.configure(background='gray')

def btnWork():
    anyVar.set("wow!!!")

myBtn=Button(text="click",
             command=btnWork)
myBtn.pack()

anyVar = StringVar()
anyVar.set("0")

myLabel=Label(textvariable = "anyVar",
              width = 10)
myLabel.pack()

mainloop()
```

Comment: It should be `textvariable=anyVar`

Comment: ahh yes, thanks so much, I'm such a noob and working with variations of this function explain so much to me. I have one last question about this which I will make another post for. It compares two fuinctions, one works yet the second one doesn't. Thanks Bryan

Comment: Bryan Oakley, not sure how to give you credit for your answer, I hope my post below will do it for you.

Answer (score 2):

From Bryan Oakley's comments, the code should be:

```
myLabel=Label(textvariable = anyVar
```

Thanks Bryan

Answer (score 1):

This is my approach without an instance of `StringVar`:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

lab = Label(text="hello", width=10)
lab.pack()

def callback():
    lab.config(text='world') # Use config to change the value of 'text'

btn = Button(text="click me", command=callback)
btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: working with ` StringVar` is the problem I need answered. I'm familiar with .config. Working with StringVar confuses me, yet some folks can make this work. Sure would like to know how to do this with StringVar ... Thanks